# Any better way to save dates in db than time()?

Tags: php, mysql

I am used to save dates in db as INT(11) with a `time()`.
Considering the limitation of time() are there any better way to save that?

I would like to NOT use the database own DATE type (and all the db own date functions).

Thanks

Comment: The date type provided by the database *is* the better way. Why don't you want to use it? Why are you after a 3rd option when the *correct* option is provided for you?

Comment: Why would you not use the built-in DATE and DATETIME column types?

Comment: because I am used to manage dates with my programming language (php in this case)

Comment: @yes123 I understand your concerns perfectly. I've long stopped using DATE and DATETIME, too much pain fixing compatibility issues. That said, if `time()` is the limit, there's no reason the DB would do it any better.

Comment: DATE would be best, as without it you lose lots of useful functions. INT(11) would be the next best choice, as INT is fast to process. What limitation of time() are you looking to avoid? What is wrong with DATE?

Comment: @Phil Lello That's not entirely true. You can "cast"(convert) a timestamp to a mysql date inside a query, thus you won't loose any functionality. The problem with DATE is that it is stored in a specific format easily confused by non-US people (amongst the many issues).

Comment: @christian perhaps mysql is different but don't most dbs store an offset of the epoch rather than a formatted date time

Comment: Anyway I am asking time() beacaue is heard that time() only works up to 2038. Am I wrong? if i am wrong i will just stick with time

Comment: @Christian As a European (living in Canada so used to dd/mm and mm/dd) I don't see how remembering to format correctly is an issue - 1 wrapper function for the value for insert/update, and DATE_FORMAT in queries (or create a view using DATE_FORMAT).

Comment: @Christian Sciberras non-US people are perfectly capable of reading YYYY-MM-DD and are already using it with files or folders because that's the only way you can sort dates correctly. Anyway, this is irrelevant because you never display a DATE field as is.

Comment: It drives me crazy, how people won't understand 1 simple rule: queries with "NOW()" and other date-functions, CAN NOT BE CACHED BY MYSQL!!!

Comment: @OZ_ No one's arguing with that; query caching is only an issue if it's relevant to the specific problem.

Comment: @ConradFrix - I don't know. but the input to a DATE must have a specific format, as does the output. @PhilLello - Of course, now put that wrapper idea of yours around everything else, and we'll talk about wasting time with conversions after that.

Comment: @Capsule - Sure thing! Non-US people like me also understand stuff like how the NSE works, for example, and I've never American touched soil - that doesn't mean everyone could/should be taking localization for granted. As to file ordering, wonder of wonders, timestamps are progressive, if you're ordering by written format, you're most probably doing it wrong (at the very least, PHP is faster at ordering by number than a string). With regards to relevance, you have to convert and format the string date, always. With a fixed timestamp, you just format the string.

Comment: @Christian, I was not talking about PHP ordering when talking about files/folders but manual ordering with user created stuff :-)

Comment: @OZ to be more question centric, it will sure be able to cache a query filled with `time()` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` but this cache will never be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, from the comments, I understand that the problem with using time() is that we're looking to represent dates outside the 01/01/1970 to whenever/2038 range.

In this case, I think it's best to format dates for the DB as `YmdHis`, stored in a BIGINT (or just `Ymd` in INT if time isn't needed). You can get use `date_create("now")->format($fmt)` instead of `time()`, and where $fmt is either 'Ymd' for date-only or 'YmdHis' for date+time

This gives a latest date somewhere in 922,337,203AD and an earliest in -922,337,203BC with time, or 214,748AD to -214,748BC in an INT with no time.

Comment: finally someneone saying something useful

Comment: anyway i tried the format(fmt): it prints: `f0430` is that a normal value? f is the year? lol

Comment: Ah, no, fmt was a placeholder, for either 'YmdHis' or 'Ymd' :O

Comment: yea i got it.. storing in db a plain 20110429 as it was an int... yes maybe it can do his job

Comment: @Phil, +1 for answering the exact question. @yes123, writing a custom date format is asking for pain and I think you'll realize this in 6 months when you need to maintain or scale your code.

Comment: @jason: isn't this almost similar to store time() in db? I think millions of sites do it without any problem

Comment: @yes123, seems like that notion might be off when the highest ranked responses on this page encourage you to do this natively. But sure, *millions* of other sites do this.

Comment: @yes123 you'll change your mind when once you'll need to something like "Get all records of every Thursday of the second week of every third month of the year 2009 based on BIGINT field", briefly you'll need to reproduce the calculus made by the standard DB functions.

Comment: @igor: I strongly believe I will never need a query like that

Comment: And of course, it it ever does become an issue, the code/database can be updated (easy as long as date code is in a couple of functions rather than inline)

Comment: @Phil According to the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) The supported range for DATETIME is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. So where did the 1970 thing come from?

Comment: @Conrad From the first line of the question. The OP has reasons to use an INT instead of DATETIME, but can't use the int returned by PHP's time(), as the result is relative to 1970, and the OP needs the DB to support earlier dates. It's possible old records are getting computerised, or he's dealing with dates-of-birth, or any number of things.

Comment: @Phil oh ok so it was PHP concern not a MySQL one. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`.

It's constant for the whole request and it's faster than `time()` (and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`) because it only requires an array lookup instead of a function call.

Comment: I don't worry at all about time() slowness

Comment: If performance isn't the problem then you should use DATE/DATETIME. You could switch to a fully custom time system, for instance julian dates (which start at -4713 BC) but I've found it a pain in the butt.

Comment: That's irrelevant. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` is faster, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: For direct use in PHP: yes, 200%. For SQL, in theory yes but who says MySQL doesn't use a similar faster method when calling `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`? Another problem is if PHP and MySQL are not set to the same timezone, later DATE/TIME calculations will be wrong.

Comment: Unlikely, but go ahead and test this if you want. And luckily the unix timestamp is unaffected by timezone as it's defined in GMT (I think).

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to avoid the standard time managing in DB. Have you ever considered all possible ways of representing if the correctly formated date field?

[MySQL::Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

[PostgreSQL::functions datetime](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Storing the date in the correct format is more flexible and more efficient in some cases.

Comment: It is not *flexible*, but outright *limiting*, it can be more error prone as well as not intuitive. As to efficiency, I sure hope the mess they did is at least efficient...

Comment: What part of "I would like to NOT use the database []" didn't you get

Comment: Never-ever had any probs with that, if you ever studied the 60-based calculus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics. Thats why you're suffering, you're familiar with the 10-based calculus and seconds-minutes-hours-months-years are base-60 :) Good luck to you with Babylon!

Comment: @yes123 If we don't understand why you want to avoid INT and DATE, how do we know what you'll like?

Comment: @phil i can use INT that's not a problem. I believe the problem is just with time() that supports up to 2038

Answer (score 0):

Datetimes are more readable for debugging and reading but the same amount of effort as timestamps for date formatting, the NOW keyword in the query makes things clean and tidy too, especially if you don't need the variable apart form the query:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`,`title`,`created`) VALUES (NULL, 'my awesome record', NOW());
```

Comment: It's **harder** to format a DATETIME since you end up turning it into a timestamp and then back to whatever format you desired.

Comment: Not really harder if you do it in the query: select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());

Comment: Yes, but you can't represent dates before 1970 jan 1 with timestamps, so either it's hard or impossible, take your pick ;)

Comment: sorry i missed the ***(and all the db own date functions)*** point in the post.

Comment: @Frits - That's just myth ;). I've been able to save down to 1600 in the past (I'm talking about a specific case), and it worked like a charm.

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, the platform build defines the size of integers which in turn define the date range you can cover. Also, negative timestamps work well with dates older than 1700 (go on and try `date('Y',-200000000)` => 1963).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the built in database types for dates and times, or you could just make three integer columns in your table and save the date as integers.  Whatever works and is easy to deal with.